# Error in installing SetupTools in Linux

Tags: python, linux, setuptools

So i trying install setuptools on a new server, so i got with

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

and trying to `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` in the directory where the file is located and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command.easy_install
```

I couldn't find any way of debugging this anywhere.

When I try

```
import sys
from setuptools.command.easy_install import bootstrap
sys.exit(bootstrap())
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command.easy_install
```

When I enter `sys.path` in python interpreter it gives me the following:

```
['', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-linux3', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong; you can see the exact contents of the shell script in [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13399213) if you need a starting point.

Comment: Are you perhaps running this in a symlinked path? Wild guess, perhaps `os.path.abspath('$0')` is resolving the link wrong.

Comment: not sure, I am new to Linux 
I just upgraded Python to 2.7 and at the end of the turorial it gave me this error

Comment: strangest part, the error is Pythonic, I get same one when I tried the bootstrap method you posted

Comment: Okay, next test: does `import zipfile` work? If so, does `zipfile. is_zipfile('setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg')` return True or False?

Comment: import works, return value is False

Comment: That looks like your file has been truncated; I've added some more info to my answer to tripple-check but it looks like you need to download the file again.

Comment: it is not letting me delete items in WinSCP "permission denied", need login as root i assume for it?

Comment: I have no idea how you connect to the server, sorry. You could make a new subdirectory, cd to it, re-download and install that if you are having problems with the first file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a few different things:

- move the file to a different directory, cd to the same directory, and again try running `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`.
- Open the python2.7 interactive prompt (just run `python2.7`) in the same directory as where the file resides. Then run:

  ```
  import sys
  from setuptools.command.easy_install import bootstrap
  sys.exit(bootstrap())
  ```

  to attempt the installation manually
- If that still doesn't work, run `python2.7` and run the following python code, and add the information shown to your question:

  ```
  import sys
  import setuptools

  print 'Path:', sys.path
  print 'setuptools package:', setuptools.__file__
  ```

Last but not least, test that the downloaded egg was not somehow corrupted or truncated. Test for the md5 hash and size:

```
$ md5 setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg 
MD5 (setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg) = fe1f997bc722265116870bc7919059ea
$ ls -l setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg 
-rw-r--r--  1 own  grp  332005 Jul  8  2010 setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

If they don't match, redownload the file and try again.

Comment: Last 2 methods do not work, they produce an error
First method I cant do for some reason, when I try to move the file in WinSCP it doesnt allow and gives me an error

Comment: @rodling: please add the full traceback of the errors to your question, if different from what you have now. If `import setuptools` fails, please show the `sys.path` value.