# Why does easy_install work with some Windows binaries?

Tags: python, windows, executable, easy-install

#### Background

Windows does not include a compiler by default, and installing a compiler (and perhaps configuring Python to use it) is a complicated enough task that many developers avoid doing so. To this end, many packages that have binary dependencies are available as a precompiled Windows executable that contains binary files. As an example, there is [psycopg](http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

The executable file is an installer. When executed, it provides a graphical interface that locates an installed version of Python via the registry, and it installs the Python library and the included binary dependencies in the global Python installation.

However, this is not always desirable. Particularly when using virtualenv, developers don't want to install the library globally. They want the library installed in the virtual environment. Since this environment is not represented in the registry, the graphical installer cannot locate it. Luckily, a command similar to the following can be used to install the library to the virtual environment:

```
C:\> C:\virtualenv\Scripts\activate.bat
(virtualenv) C:\> easy_install psycopg2-2.5.win32-py2.7-pg9.2.4-release.exe
```

Note that this works regardless of whether easy_install comes from setuptools or distribute.

#### The actual question

Why does this command work? What is it about the exe that allows easy_install to process it?

I have noticed that the exe seems to be some kind of zip file. 7-Zip is able to open it for browsing, and these exe files that easy_install can process seem to have a common file structure. They have a top directory named PLATLIB which contains an egg-info file or folder and another (possibly more than 1?) folder. Are these exes just Python eggs with some kind of executable wrapped around them? How might I produce one myself? (Or to word it differently, is there some standard way of producing exes like this?)

#### Edit

Bonus question: Why **doesn't** pip work with these files?

Comment: The ZIP format is defined by a structure at the *end* of the file, leaving room at the start for extra data. The [`setuptools` installer uses that trick too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399118/when-i-run-the-setuptools-egg-as-if-it-were-a-shell-script-whats-actually-h/13399213#13399213). I *think* these files have an EXE payload at the start to unzip the file to install.

Comment: Bonus comment: `pip` doesn't normally support binary eggs, only source distributions. Use the `--egg` option to install eggs with `pip`.

Comment: Pip will support a new binary format called *wheel*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried using `--egg` with one of these binaries. I just got errors. Did you only mean non-binary eggs?

Comment: @jpmc26: It could be that `pip` still won't handle those eggs even with `--egg`.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: `wheel` has different goals than eggs, IIRC.