# python setup.py install shows success message but pip freeze cannot see and script is not a valid command

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to install a package that I just developed locally (Python 3.6, setuptools 35.0.2) and I see success message:

```
Copying mon_agent-0.0.1-py3.6.egg to /home/jgu/repos/.venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
mon-agent 0.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing mon_agent_worker.py script to /home/jgu/repos/.venv36/bin

Installed /home/jgu/repos/.venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mon_agent-0.0.1-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for mon-agent==0.0.1
Finished processing dependencies for mon-agent==0.0.1
```

But when I do `pip freeze | grep mon` (I did pip list and did not find mon_agent either) I see nothing and when I type mon_agent_worker in command line, it says command does not exist.

I can open python shell and import mon_agent and prints out it version and use it normally. However I cannot run script -- command not found

Edit:

I just run `python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal` and `pip install mon_agent-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and the script is working, and pip freeze shows it

Edit (Added my setup.py for more debugging info):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

import mon_agent

NAME = 'mon_agent'
PACKAGES = [
    'mon_agent', 'mon_agent.collectors'
]
PACKAGE_DATA = {
    '': ['resources/*.txt']
}
AUTHOR = mon_agent.__author__
AUTHOR_EMAIL = 'franklingujunchao@gmail.com'
URL = '***something***'


REQUIRES = []
with open('requirements.txt', 'r') as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        REQUIRES.append(line.strip())
VERSION = mon_agent.__version__
DESCRIPTION = 'Log monitor agent'
KEYWORDS = 'monitor data log agent'
LONG_DESC = mon_agent.__doc__

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=AUTHOR_EMAIL,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=LONG_DESC,
    url=URL,
    keywords=KEYWORDS,
    scripts=['bin/mon_agent_worker'],
    package_dir={'': './'},
    packages=PACKAGES,
    package_data=PACKAGE_DATA,
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=REQUIRES,
    python_requires='>=3.5',
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
    ],
)
```

Comment: Do you see your package listed under `pip list`?

Comment: pip list did not give me mon_agent :(

Comment: If the only thing missing is the command, there's probably something wrong with the command specification in your `setup.py` file.

Comment: The normal way of getting setuptools to generate an executable at install time is to use `entry_points`. I don't see an entry point specified in your setup.py file.

Comment: but the pip way works as expected for me... I will read more about setup tools

Comment: You need to start using `@username` to notify people when you respond. Anyway, pip and setuptools do different things nowadays. setuptools builds packages. pip installs packages built by setuptools. setuptools originally had infrastructure for installing packages, but it's mostly not used nowadays. The only reason you'd really need it is if you needed to use setuptools' install mechanism now is to install one of the [old, legacy executable binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16618289/1394393). Although even these can be converted directly into wheels now.

Comment: @jpmc26 , OK got it. Thanks